# WSO2 EMM compatibility with Postgres

Tags: wso2-iot

I would like to know whether WSO2 EMM is compatible with PostgreSQL database. Can we configure Postgres as the WSO2 EMM DB instead of MySQL.

Thanks,
Srini

Answer (score 0):

Yes but there is no postgre sql script added in EMM. You could use the same mysql db script and change if necessary. This could be found in dbscripts. After that change the repository/conf/datasources/master-datasources.xml file accordingly to point to your database. Also you will need the postgre JDBC connector added in repository/components/lib as well.

Answer (score 0):

but the EMM is developed by jaggery JS which doesn't talk to postgre sql. How can it work?